# Unhandled promise Rejection (rejection id: 1) - Node.js

Tags: node.js, controller, promise, postman

I'm new to Node.js and trying to figure out of some problems.
I've defined a signup function on a Node.js server for an Android app who writes user's info on MongoDB.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = require('./api/models/serverModel'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ProjectDB";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(url); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes/serverRoute');
routes(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Project RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

**serverModel**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: {type: String, required: true}
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

module.exports = User;

**serverRoute**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var Project = require('../controllers/serverController');

  // Project Routes
    app.route('/signup')
        .post(Project.signup);
};
```

**serverController**

```
...
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
exports.signup = function(req, res)  {

return new Promise( function(resolve,reject) {

    var user = new User({
       userName: req.body.name,
       password: req.body.pass,
       mail: req.body.email,
       createdAt : new Date()
    });

user.save()
    .then(function() { resolve({ status: 201, message: 'User Registered Successfully !' })})
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err.code == 11000) {
            reject({ status: 409, message: 'User Already Registered !' });
        } else {
            reject({ status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error !' });
        }
    });

})};

...
```

It compiles without any error. 
When I try to send a JSON via Postman like this:

```
{
  "userName" : "username",
  "email" : "user.name@gmail.com",
  "password" : "blabla1"
}
```

it reports

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise Rejection (rejection id: 1) [object Object]

I've read tons of posts but I can't get out of this.
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: share the code where you use signup function.

Comment: @mehta-rohan I Simply add the route

Comment: @mehta-rohan and the call it from postman (POST - http://localhost:3000/signup)

Comment: it's not possible to solve without seeing. your signup function returns a promise which must me handled on the other end, look carefully or share.

Comment: @mehta-rohan all project reported...

Comment: So this is the culprit- // Project Routes app.route('/signup') .post(Project.signup); your Project.signup returns a promise which is not  handled. You need to make changes here

Comment: @mehta-rohan could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151612/discussion-between-jacklametta-and-mehta-rohan).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and revert.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = require('./api/models/serverModel'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ProjectDB";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(url); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes/serverRoute');
//change 
//routes(app);
app.use('/',routes);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Project RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

**serverRoute**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// GET home page. 
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    var Project = require('../controllers/serverController');
    Project.signup().then(function(result){
    res.send(result);
  }).catch(function(err){
      res.send(err);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```